# Does anyone have any tips on submitting to clients proposals for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, clients

I'm just starting out with a friend creating iPhone apps and the biggest hurdle other than finding clients is knowing how to structure proposals for clients.

Is it the norm to write a 1, 2 or 3 page proposal? Obviously I don't want to bore the client just with the initial proposal (sales pitch with quote).

How should I break down the pricing? Should I be completely transparent and put the amount of hours for development, amount for design, amount for research and liaison with the company etc?

Does anyone know of any samples online?

Any help would be really gratefully appreciated.

Comment: As this is more of a business question than a programming one, it's offtopic for this site.  However, this same question has been asked before on the iPhone Software Business mailing list, so I'd direct you there: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb

Answer (score 2):

My strong suggestion is several fold (bearing in mind that these are just suggestions, and flexible based on what your gut is telling you about the client):

- **Sales fluff, is exactly that, fluff**. In general, stand out rather than trying to sell them on you, sell them your excitement about the project, rather than your experience, ability to deliver in a timely manner, these are all things they expect from you anyway. Show them something different—And keep it short.
- **Keep your proposal simple**. Most people, typically don't want to have to read more than a couple pages of text in these cases.
- **Quote how you are comfortable**. I generally quote estimated hours, clearly mark as such, and provide short information as to my last few projects, what I estimated and what I completed, even if I went over time (which occasionally has happened). You will get better with time as to your time estimates, but try to be as accurate as you think you can be, but don't stress over it.

There are exceptions to every rule though, so keep that in mind.